# What exception to raise on failing fixture?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, fixtures

I use pytest and have some fixtures in my `conftest.py` file that call a web service to create some resources. Now obviously these requests may fail for whatever reason.

I realize it doesn't matter much as any exception will fail the test run, but I wondered what type of exception to raise in this case.

Should I just call the `raise_for_status` method on the response? Or do I define my own exception like `FixtureError`. What is the convention when handling failure modes in a fixture?

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea not to use fixtures like that, at all? I don't know your usecase, but I would normally either mock a web service or create fixed fixtures. Otherwise create an own error for that, seems also reasonable.

Comment: These "failures" are not python exceptions but, rather, undesirable responses?

Comment: Yes, I'm registering something with the SUT that tests later depend on being there. In my case, the fixture is not actually calling the web service, but using the Flask test client to call, but that is not really relevant here.